# How to find levels for each discrete variable group

Tags: r, dplyr

Not sure exactly how to title my question so please provide feedback if I can make it more clear.

I have a dataframe where a couple of the columns look similar to this:

```
    Node     Component  Value
1     A        os.name RedHat
2     A     os.version  16.04
3     A docker.version 1.13.1
4     A kernel.version 3.10.0
5     B        os.name RedHat
6     B     os.version  16.04
7     B docker.version 1.12.1
8     B kernel.version 3.11.0
9     C        os.name Ubuntu
10    C     os.version  18.04
11    C docker.version 1.12.1
12    C kernel.version 3.12.0
13    D        os.name RedHat
14    D     os.version  17.04
15    D docker.version 1.13.1
16    D kernel.version 3.13.0
```

Which can be reproduced with:

```
    structure(list(Node = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D"), class = "factor"), Component = structure(c(3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("docker.version", 
"kernel.version", "os.name", "os.version"), class = "factor"), 
    Value = structure(c(10L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 10L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 11L, 
    5L, 1L, 8L, 10L, 4L, 2L, 9L), .Label = c("1.12.1", "1.13.1", 
    "16.04", "17.04", "18.04", "3.10.0", "3.11.0", "3.12.0", 
    "3.13.0", "RedHat", "Ubuntu"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

This data is being rendered in a shiny app that is used to find nodes that are not using the correct version (represented by value) of a component. I have created a "baseline" dataframe that lists what version a component should be on, and using the rpivotTable package, I display the nodes that do not match this "baseline". In some cases, the baseline may need to be updated by the user. I am trying to determine a way to present the user with all of the possible values for each component, so they can reactively modify the baseline and the pivot table will update.

I considered using select inputs in the ui and maybe even a handsontable but I cannot figure out how to render these selections without hard coding them into the "choices" or "levels" which is why I am here. Note: there are more than 100 components to I plan to use a loop to dynamically generate the selectInput or use a handsontable instead).

Is there a way to access the levels for each variable group? For example, the user would modify the baseline for os.verion and select either 16.04, 17.04, or 18.04 as the target baseline. Is there a way to leverage group_by for this?

Here is a sample app of what I am trying to accomplish with the ui without having to manually configure the choices:
[image: Example ui]

**EDIT:**

Hopefully this will provide some better clarification to what I am asking. In the same way `levels(df$Component)` provides the factor levels for the Component category, is there a way to drill down to each component to get it's levels? I know some functions are able to accomplish this in some way such as how

```
df %>% group_by(Component) %>%
  add_count(Value)
```

provides counts based upon the Value grouped by Component.

Comment: Any code sample?

Comment: I provided sample data, are you asking for a code sample of the app?

Comment: Yes please, for most people, it'd be much easier to improve what you have than to write everything from scratch. Since a shinyApp is hard to reproduce, just providing the relevant parts of the app should be sufficient.

Comment: Well my question is more specific to how you access those levels of the group (or if it is even possible) rather than making it work in shiny. I was trying to avoid making the question too long. I'll update the question with some app code as well.

Comment: Well, when asking questions on SO, people expect the OP to have put in some effort at solving the problem. So at the very least you should provide some code sample of the part where you were stuck instead of just describing it. _"how to render these selections without hard coding them into the "choices" or "levels" which is why I am here."_ maybe start by showing which part you were trying to avoid hardcoding?

Comment: I understand that, I have been frequenting SO for years. As I mentioned above, I am not exactly sure how to title my question - so maybe the question itself needs clarification as I think the answer to my question can be derived sans shiny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the solution is to reshape your data from long to wide format. Currently, you have every aspect of a node on its own row, which makes it hard to find out what values it can have. If you reshape the data into the wide format, it will be easy to access.

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)

newdf <- spread(df, Component, Value, convert = TRUE)

#   Node docker.version kernel.version os.name os.version
# 1    A         1.13.1         3.10.0  RedHat      16.04
# 2    B         1.12.1         3.11.0  RedHat      16.04
# 3    C         1.12.1         3.12.0  Ubuntu      18.04
# 4    D         1.13.1         3.13.0  RedHat      17.04

unique(newdf$docker.version)

# [1] "1.13.1" "1.12.1"
```

The setting `convert = TRUE` automatically chooses a suitable data type for the new columns. You need to check if you want this to happen. In this case, the os.version column is of numeric type, which you might not want. It also transforms string columns into character rather than factor data type. This means you can access unique values using `unique` or you can use `levels` after transforming them back into factors.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of this! I already spent some time reshaping the data for other purposes. Thanks! I am going to test this out and see if this gets me where I need to be.